# Using Multidimensional arrays in modular program

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to make a module that lets the user type 1-4 to select the column(riesling, chardonnay) and from that column, they choose a row(the variation they desire)

The problem I ran into: How do I make the for loops for that? My wineTypes array is strings, so when I return wineTypes[][] it actually gives me an error, should I return string instead?

I just need some help with the module for getting their selections, and tracking the total/most ordered in another module.

Instructor prompt: [image]

My code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class WineCalc{

public static void main(String[] args){

  String[][]wineTypes = {
                        {"Riesling", "Chardonnay", "Sauvignon Blanc", "Merlot"},
                        {"Dry- $4.50", "Apple- $6.00", "Lime-$4.50", "Plum- $5.00"},
                        {"Off Dry-$4.00", "Lemon-$5.50", "Lemongrass- $6.50", "Black Cherry- $7.50"},
                        {"Sweet- $5.00", "Vanilla- $6.00", "Coconut- $7.00", "Chocolate- $6.00"},
                        };
  double[][]prices = {
                     {4.50, 6.00, 4.50, 5.00},
                     {4.00, 5.50, 6.50, 7.50},
                     {5.00, 6.00, 7.00, 6.00},
                     };

  int[][]counter = {
                   {0,0,0,0},
                   {0,0,0,0},
                   {0,0,0,0},
                   };


}

public static int getWineType(String wineTypes[][]){
  for(i=0; i<wineTypes[0].length;i++){
     for(int j=0; j<wineTypes.length; j++){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, wineTypes[i][j]);
   }
  }




return wineTypes[][];
}
}
```

Comment: Your indexes are reversed.

Comment: it should be j, then i? Should this method be the same one that I let the user enter their column, and row? Dunno how to equate the two inputs, which are numbers, to columns and rows.

Comment: no...you are accessing the child before the parent in the first loop...I'll post answer.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. Shouldn't I put a while(index<16 && exitVar == false) loop around it all, so that each time they enter a column or row, it increments? And if they type -1 for any row or column they want to access, then it sets exitVar to true.

Comment: You can do even better than that. Have your "data access" loop separated from the "user interface". Make a function that takes `column` and `row` as parameters, and that returns, for example, `wineTypes[column][row]` (after checking if that column and row are valid, ie. equal or greater than `0` and less than their array's `length`), that way you don't need to loop through the whole table to access a single item. --- You can move the loop code into another function that is specific to when you actually want to print the whole table.

Comment: I see. So, this would print out the entire table to the user? And I should gather the input for which column and row the user wants within another method? or all within this same method that prints out the menu to the user, like in the prompt up above?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97725/discussion-between-thelima-and-hello).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## EDIT:

Taking into account a brief *chat* I had with the OP, in which the problems he is having were explained in a bit more detail, I've decided that the best way to help him is with an example that will clarify how to solve the problems he is having with the assignment, while being careful not to give off the answer to the assignment:

```
  public static String[] wineTypes = {"Riesling", "Chardonnay", "Sauvignon Blanc", "Merlot"};
  public static String[][] wineVariations = {
    {"Dry- $4.50", "Off Dry-$4.00", "Sweet- $5.00"},
    {"Apple- $6.00", "Lemon-$5.50", "Vanilla- $6.00"},
    {"Lime-$4.50", "Lemongrass- $6.50", "Coconut- $7.00"},
    {"Plum- $5.00", "Black Cherry- $7.50", "Chocolate- $6.00"}
  };

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    do {
      String wineType = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
              "Select wine type:",
              "Input - Wine Type - (Column)",
              JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
              null,
              wineTypes,
              wineTypes[0]);
      if (wineType == null) {
        System.out.println("NULL!");
      } else {
        System.out.println(wineType);
      }
      /*
      Do "the same" for the variations within the selected type.
      Tip: If you can use ArrayLists instead of Arrays, it will make it a lot easier to get the indexes of the choices...
      ...This, in turn, would make the second loop, and the processing of the prices, much easier...
      ...Just be careful with the last rule in your assignment; make sure it was covered, or don't use it.
      Tip: You will need a loop to get the correct array of options...
      ...And you'll need to contain that loop within a function, and return only the result, in order to use it as parameter to the JOptionPane.
      */
      /*
      Except for the main loop, I left the handling of the "cancel" buttons to you as well.
      */
    } while (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Continue?", "Input - Continue", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == 0);
  }
```

Comment: How come I got so many errors when compiling that? Would this show the entire menu to the user? Can you help me make the input dialogs for asking the user for the column and row they want?

Comment: If you don't tell what errors you're getting, it's hard to help any further than this. As for helping, I can help you understand what's going wrong with your own code, but I have my own projects, and I can't code your stuff for you.